# ionic 1 - selected option from sidemenu not displaying in its parent view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

1) Main page is *index.html* 
2) By default, Using router config i redirect to login page - *template/login.html*
3) From login page, if login successful, i will redirect to the home page with sidemenu - *template/landing.html*
4) In homepage, when i click the hamburger icon, i get sidemenu with options
 
5) But when i click an option in sidemenu, for example "updateProfile" *template/updateProfile.html* , i'm not able to see the corresponding updateProfile page in homepage

i tried making changes in config, but i'm not making any progress. kindly help me out.

Below is my code.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

**template/login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign in">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content>
         <input type="text" placeholder="@handle" ng-model="userName" />
         <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn()">Sign in</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
 app.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$state){
            $state.go('landing');
        };
      });

app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('login',{
      url : '/',
      templateUrl : 'template/login.html',
      controller : 'LoginController',
      cache : false
    });

    $stateProvider.state('landing',{
      url : '/landing',
      templateUrl : 'template/landing.html',
      controller : 'LandingController'
    }).state('landing.updateProfile', {
            url: "/updateProfile",
            views: {
                'menuContent' : {
                    templateUrl: "template/updateProfile.html"
                }
            }
        });


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
```

**template/landing.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Landing">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-side-menus>
            <ion-side-menu-content>
                <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
                    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon"></button>
                    </ion-nav-buttons>
                    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
                </ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-side-menu side="left">
                <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable"><h4>Do your thing</h4></ion-header-bar>
                <ion-content>
                    <ion-list>
                        <ion-item menu-close href="#/updateProfile">Update Profile</ion-item>
                        <ion-item menu-close href="#/yourDishes">Your Events</ion-item>
                    </ion-list>
                </ion-content>    
            </ion-side-menu>            
        </ion-side-menus>
</ion-view>
```

**template/updateProfile.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Update Profile">
    <ion-content>
        update profile
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the issue fixed.
**in template/landing.html** href should be of below format, only then it will match the corresponding url mentioned in the config function.

```
 <ion-item menu-close href="#/landing/updateProfile">Update Profile</ion-item>
 <ion-item menu-close href="#/landing/yourDishes">Your Events</ion-item>
```